# How to store table or matrix in Java?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, matrix

I used to use matrix in octave to store data from data set, in Java how can I do that? Assume I have 10-20 columns and large data, I don't think

```
int [][]data;
```

would be the best option. Is nested map the only solution?

Comment: Map is the most fitted solution and the easiest to use

Comment: Why not `int[][]`? When you say _store_, you mean **writing this data to the disk** or just **storing/handling it on the memory**?

Comment: @AdelBoutros really? IMHO, if you want a simple matrix, a 2D array is the way to go. If you use a `Map`, you'll have to check that _all nested maps have the same size_, which is not necessary on 2D arrays.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the nested-array-solution; the reasons are adaptiveness of the size, and that I don't really know how large the set of data is gonna be and how nested arrays are handled in main memory. Obviously that is not too much of an issue probably since I doubt he'll build a nested array that hase more than the 4GB main memory that are probably somewhat common place by now. Nevertheless, it might be a performance issue if the code is supposed to be run on a machine that has relevant restrictions on memory-an embedded environment for example. I'd go for SJuan76's option either way.

Comment: **1)** As I said in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8976303/710951) (which combines those two approaches) SJuan76's option is good when you have dispersed “points”; if you have contineous data (e.g. every coordinate on the matrix has data) it's definitively better to store them ordered in a 2D-array. **2)** He doesn't say if he wants the matrix to be adaptative or fixed, so the correct IMHO is to give him the two ways. **Don't you think so?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you need to do. If you know the size of the lists, then an array is definitely ideal since it means you will have instant access (read/write time) to any position in the array, this is very useful for speed.

Maps are better if you dont know the size and it needs to be able to adapt.

And finally, as I discovered in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459972/avoid-an-out-of-memory-error-in-javaeclipse-when-using-large-data-structure), if you have a TON of data, and a lot of it will be "0" you might want to also consider using a [Sparse Martrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

Answer (score 5):

You could create a class `Coordinate` that takes an X and Y values and properly implement hashCode and equals.

Then create a HashMap<Coordinate, Data> and work with it.

Comment: +1 You're proposing a simple, effective and adaptative (you don't need to know the size of the matrix) way to do it.

Comment: One thing: why to make your own `Coordinate` if you can use [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)? See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8976303/710951).

Comment: Didn't think of it, but anyway I do not like relying in awt if I do not need to (possible problems if you launch java in a system without GUI -yes I know they are solvable, but why take the risk-)

Comment: There isn't any problem. Classes such as `Point` or `Color` are always present, and they can be used only as utilities (to make geometry, store data, ...) even if there's no GUI in your program. The problem comes when you _try to create_ a GUI (i.e. a `Frame`) on a non-graphical system. **I think it's safe to use `Point`.**

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This answer merges some of [gnomed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27739/gnomed)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975940/710951) and [SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598289/sjuan76)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975835/710951) contents.</sup>

1. At a quick glance, I'd suggest you to use **bidimentional arrays** such as `int[][]`.
   It's not a *very huge* amount of data (we're speaking of ≈500 ints) so it's not a bad idea.

   **Advantages:** It's the simpler, **ideal** (from the *data-structuring* side) way to go,
   *especially* if every “slot” of the matrix contains data.

   **The inconvenient:** You have to know the size of the matrix *before* constructing it.
   Anyway, you can resize it later using the `Arrays` utilities.
2. If you want more effective handling of the data, you can use a **single point-map**.
   That is, the key of every entry is a `java.awt.Point` that defines *where* is the value located.

   **Advantages:** It's more effective than having a 2D array,
   *especially* if part of your matrix doesn't contain data.
   And it's **adaptative**; you don't need to know any sizes to construct/resize it.

   **The inconvenient:** If every “slot” of your matrix contains data,
   you'll loose (a lot of) space and performance. A 2D-array is more effective then.
3. Want more? If your data is *really huge* you can use a [**sparse matrix**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).
   See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459972/avoid-an-out-of-memory-error-in-javaeclipse-when-using-large-data-structure) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would not discard multidimensional arrays so far: have you tried them? Are you finding specific limitations? IMHO as long as your data fits in memory, arrays can be good.

If your data is very sparse though, you may want to look at maps indeed.

Related question btw: [Making a very large Java array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674186/making-a-very-large-java-array)

Comment: I used them , but I was reading about arrays limitations and don't know if this apply to maps also

Answer (score 0):

You can use multidimensional arrays or you can try any  pairs like HashMap

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-dimentional arrays are the best choice! They should serve your purpose. If your data set is only integers, int [] [] is an ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

- Well, if your indices are small integers, you can certainly use nested arrays.
- In a matrix class, you may want to use a plain array, like so: (assuming n is the number of columns)

```java
double get(int i, int j) { return data[i*n + j]; }
```

- For a general table (sparse matrix), you can use nested maps, but consider using [com.google.common.collect.Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/index.html) implementations from the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.